# Unable to update plugins or log out

Tags: plugins, updates, nonce, logout

The server my site was hosted on recently went down and someone else was able to fix it for me. I am unclear on what exactly the issues with the server were, but since the site came back up, my cron events don't run.

I log in to my dashboard and try to run them manually using the WP Cron Manager plugin, and I get a `wrong nonce` error.

I then try to log out of the dashboard - I am directed to a page with the message `Are you sure you want to log out?` and when I say yes, nothing happens, I just stay on the same page.

Additionally, I tried to update the WP Cron Manager plugin but I get a vague error message: `Error -1` I also cannot activate or deactivate my plugins.

I tried the site in incognito mode (was thinking Cookie issue) and got all the same error messages.

What else should I try? Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: enable the maximum debug log as explained here : https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: @Kaperto thanks, I have debug.log enabled in `wp-config.php`.

Comment: Any info from the error logs? in the site root and in wp-admin. And the usual stuff of disabling plugins by renaming the plugins folder to see if there is a plugin issue.

Comment: @RickHellewell so far nothing useful in the error log. I tested it by adding a typo in the code and the error log does appear in the site root. I am not seeing an error log in wp-admin...

Comment: @RickHellewell Just tried renaming the plugin folder - no changes

Comment: Can you log into admin? Does the site content appear OK? Have you tried one of the 'twenty' themes? And looked for inserted code in the wp-config/wp-settings/index files? And looked at the htaccess file?

Comment: @RickHellewell if I go to incognito mode I can log in to the site - I can't logout however

Comment: @RickHellewell no problems with the site content, it looks normal.

Comment: I did modify the wp-config.php file, but the version I am using is the same as the one before the server upgrade. The other files are also the same

Comment: Login incognito as admin. Update WordPress (even if current). If still problems, change to one of the 'twenty' themes. If still problems, disable all plugins (still on the 'twenty' theme). If OK then, re-enable plugins one at a time (still with 'twenty' theme) to find bad plugin. If still issue, reload all plugin code (download the zip from repository, uncompress local, ftp local to site in proper folder). If 'twenty' works, but your theme doesn't, download theme from repository source, unzip, FTP upload to site.  
Look at all index.php files for bad code.

Comment: @RickHellewell thank you for your help - I'm not able to update Wordpress for some reason. I can see that there is an update available, but when I try it I get 'the link you followed has expired'

Comment: You should be able to update via the Admin, Update screen. Or manually, which is a bit more involved. What version of WP do you have now?